# Where is this SQL statement bottlenecking?

Tags: sql, optimization, sybase, sql-execution-plan

I am trying to write a SQL (Sybase) query to fetch movie theatre information out of a database. When I run the query below, the query just keeps running. Eventually, after 5 minutes or so, I just abort it. There's no bad/illegal SQL, it's just **slow**!

```
SELECT
    TM.type_prefix +
        right('00000000' + convert(varchar, TM.showing_id), 8) +
        right('0000' + convert(varchar, TM.theatre_id), 4) as data_id
FROM
    theatre_times..theatre_mappings TM,
    theatres..region_codes RC,
    title_summaries..movie_summary MS
WHERE
    TM.scheme_id = 512 AND
    RC.region_code_id = MS.region_code_id
```

Don't worry about the table names or logic used in the query, I'm just wondering if there's anything **obvious** that I'm doing wrong or inefficiently. Here are the counts for all three tables:

- `theatre_mappings` = 2,094,163
- `region_codes` = 11,140,348
- `movie_summary` = 6,437,782

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have this... `tm CROSS JOIN (rc INNER JOIN ms ON RC.region_code_id = MS.region_code_id)` Is that really correct? Or is there a field that should be used to join `tm` to `rc`, or `tm` to `ms`? Also, note, if you use explicit `JOIN` syntax, it becomes much harder to make these mistakes. *(If, indeed, it **is** a mistake.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its producing a Cartesian because you're not joining the `theatre_mappings` table to the other two.. Without seeing your schema, I can't say for sure, but I suspect you need something like:

```
SELECT
    TM.type_prefix +
        right('00000000' + convert(varchar, TM.showing_id), 8) +
        right('0000' + convert(varchar, TM.theatre_id), 4) as data_id
FROM
    theatre_times..theatre_mappings TM,
    theatres..region_codes RC,
    title_summaries..movie_summary MS
WHERE
    TM.scheme_id = 512 AND
    TM.region_code_id = RC.region_code_id  -- Extra join
    RC.region_code_id = MS.region_code_id
```

Comment: @orionTurtle - I ***strongly*** recommend you use explicit `JOIN` sysntax to avoid these types of problems.  `ANSI-92` has had 20 years of adoption, I think that's long enough...

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a cartesian product of TM entries to (RC/MS) entries. Do you want to be?

I think Sybase supports ANSI 92 SQL syntax, so your SQL is equivalent to

```
FROM
    theatre_times..theatre_mappings TM,

    theatres..region_codes RC
          inner join title_summaries..movie_summary MS
          on RC.region_code_id = MS.region_code_id
WHERE
    TM.scheme_id = 512
```